# Sylius: Mailer not working, add my own

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer, sylius

Ever since I started working with Sylius in February I haven't ever gotten an email in any step in the e-commerce process. Not when registering, not when an order was completed.

Now I assumed there simply was no support for this and I started writing my own mailer that accepts an Order and User object to fill in the mail. Today I figured out that there -is- a Mailer in the `SyliusCoreBundle` which fails to send any email at all.

Manually calling the `SwiftMailer` sends emails just fine -- it even sends it to the developer email address defined in `config_dev.yml` when in the development environment.

This brings me with two questions:

1. How could it be that the Sylius Mailer does not function like it should?
2. How can I best add my own mailing function when an Order is complete or a User registered a new account?

I've looked at "[How to override Sylius email system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23626938/how-to-override-sylius-email-system)" which offers a potential solution to the second question, would like to know if this is the way to go.

**Edit:** I'm using Sylius 0.10.0x
 It would appear that the `sylius.checkout.finalize.complete` is fired, though it never sends the mail at this point. It does when I manually call it elsewhere:

```
xxx.listener.order.confirmation:
    class: Xxx\Bundle\CoreBundle\EventListener\OrderListener
    arguments:
        - @xxx.mailer
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: sylius.checkout.finalize.complete, method: processOrderConfirmation }
```

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to figure out the same thing earlier and then realized, assuming you want the order confirmation listener to fire, that I needed to define the parameters

```
sylius.email.order_confirmation.template
```

and

```
sylius.email.order_confirmation.from_email
```

which are used in Sylius/Bundle/CoreBundle/Resources/config/mailer/order_confirmation_mailer.xml but never defined. Similar requirement for the welcome email. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `loadEmailsConfiguration()` method in  `SyliusCoreExtension` class (copied below). It checks whether you have enabled the email listener and configured it correctly before before registering it.

```php
// src/Sylius/Bundle/CoreBundle/DependencyInjection/SyliusCoreExtension.php

protected function loadEmailsConfiguration(array $config, ContainerBuilder $container, XmlFileLoader $loader)
{
    foreach ($this->emails as $emailType) {
        $loader->load('mailer/'.$emailType.'_mailer.xml');

        $fromEmail = isset($config[$emailType]['from_email']) ? $config[$emailType]['from_email'] : $config['from_email'];
        $container->setParameter(sprintf('sylius.email.%s.from_email', $emailType), array($fromEmail['address'] => $fromEmail['sender_name']));
        $container->setParameter(sprintf('sylius.email.%s.template', $emailType), $config[$emailType]['template']);

        if ($config['enabled'] && $config[$emailType]['enabled']) {
            $loader->load('mailer/'.$emailType.'_listener.xml');
        }
    }
}
```

Try adding this to your config.yml in order to get it working:

```
sylius_core:
    emails:
        enabled: true
        order_confirmation:
            enabled: true
            template: FooBundle:Checkout/Email:orderConfirmation.html.twig
            from_email: { address: foo@bar.com, sender_name: Foo Bar }
```

Note, if you want to use your own template you should extend from Sylius's `orderConfirmation.html.twig`. Sylius's `TwigSwiftMailer` mailer class requires a `subject`, `body_text` and `body_html` block in your template.

Answer (score 0):

Let me also add that you may also need:

1)This in parameters.yml

```
sylius.mailer.transport: smtp
sylius.mailer.host: localhost
sylius.mailer.user: info@xxxxx.com
sylius.mailer.password:xxxxxxx
```

2) If you have overridden SyliusWebBundle, move Resources/Frontend/Emails folder to your bundle

3) The reference shown up above for config.yml

4) Your custom customerWelcome.html.twig and orderConfirmation.html.twig, which also means translating all required messages inside them to all required languages.